# How to change AndroidStudio right margin

Tags: android-studio

The right margin in AndroidStudio is of 100 characters. I can't seem to find an option to change it to say, 120 characters. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Settings | Code Style | Right margin (columns)

Comment: thanks. i was looking for the wrong text ("right margin" is it). :)

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 4.0.1:

`File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > $filetype > Line Length:` ______ (Set it according to your convenience).

Answer (score 0):

In android studio 3.2:
go to `Settings > appearance` and `behavior > code style > hard wrap at` (enter a figure above 100 to shift the right margin)

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3.5:

Mac - Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > CodeStyle > HardWrap at: ____